# CSS Trickery: Make each line smaller

Tags: jquery, css

You know how an Eye Chart has lots of lines with jumbled up letters and each line gets smaller making it hard to read, Well is that possible with CSS? Like, I have a DIV, and it's set to `text-align: justify`, but I would like to make each line smaller.  I have no idea how to reference each subsequent line or anything.  Anyone have any ideas? It must be possible, if not with CSS with some jQuery sorcery or somesuch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/tuanderful/mQYCt/

I basically nested a bunch of divs within each other, used the child selector `>`, and a relative unit for the line-height, `em`

**► CSS**

```
div > div {
  line-height: .8em;   
  font-size: .8em;    
}
```

**► HTML**

```
<div>
  Foo
  <div>
    Foo
    <div>
      Foo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

This approach just nests a bunch of divs within each other; because of the `div > div` definition, each subsequently nested `div` is a proportion smaller than its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with some jQuery:
1) Markup

```
​<div>
    <p>This is line one</p>
    <p>This is line two</p>
    <p>This is line three</p>
    <p>This is line four</p>
    <p>This is line five</p>
    <p>This is line six</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

2) CSS (size for the biggest line)

```
​div > p:first-child {
    font-size:1.8em;
}​
```

3) JS:

```
var pars = $("div p");
var size;
for (var i = 0; i < pars.length - 1; i++) {
    size = parseInt($(pars[i]).css('font-size'));
    $(pars[i+1]).css('font-size', (size*0.9+"px"));
}​
```

If you want to decrease font-size faster - change 0.9 to smth smaller

p.s. Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/BVWp4/

Answer (score 0):

[Tuanderful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280909/tuanderful) gave probably the easiest and most browser compatible method, but I'm compiling a few more. One obvious method is series of `nth-child(#)` declarations which I've demo-ed here: http://jsfiddle.net/mQYCt/2/

```
.parent > div:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 20px;
}
...
```

If more browsers implement both `calc` and [css variables](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/) this could probably be done with a single declaration, but it's a little ways off.

I also tried (just out of curiosity) using a `counter-increment` to do this:

```
.parent {counter-reset: num;}
.parent div {
    counter-increment: num;
    font-size: -moz-calc( num * 10px);
    font-size: calc( num * 10px);
}
```

Not surprisingly, this did not work in any browser, but it was a fun thought.